# NodeJs Capture All process.stdout to File

Tags: node.js, pipe, stdout

I'm looking for a way to grab all `process.stdout` and pipe to a log file, I have the following:

```
import fs from 'fs';
let logFile = fs.createWriteStream('./test.log', {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  flags   : 'a'
});
process.stdout.pipe(logFile);
```

However, it seems to still spit all `stdout` to the console and I'm not getting anything in the log file (although it's being created).

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather have the program *only* write to `stdout` and have the process that calls node decide what to do with the output:

`node server | tee test.log`

This has a few benefits:

- Doesn't couple your code to your logging infrastructure
- Doesn't lock the file while you are writing logs (for instance, you'd need to restart your process whenever you wanted to rotate your logs -- bad for servers)

And avoids a very serious drawback:

- You don't have to monkeypatch any core node stuff which may have serious side effects somewhere else in your application (or conflicts with another library doing the same thing)

Comment: Agreed.  ```node test.js > test.log 2>&1``` works for me when casual coding for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't working because `process.stdout` is a write stream that can't be piped from, though I'm not completely sure. What I did get working was the following example, where I override stdout with a new writable stream that has a `_write` method that calls forward to the file stream's `write`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./test.log', {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  flags: 'w'
});

process.stdout = require('stream').Writable();
process.stdout._write = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    writeStream.write(chunk, encoding, callback);
};

console.log('test from console.log');
```